# Select two tables side by side

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables filled with two files of which table1 always has one row more than the second.

I want to merge the two tables into one. When I use a `right join` e.g.

```
select *
from table2
right join table1 on table1.id = table2.id and table1.eq_nb = table2.eq_nb
```

I will have the 4 combinations for `eq_nb = 25` because it is repeated two times.

But I rather want to stick the columns side by side

To know, I don't have conditions on arrival and depart time of each eq_nb (I can't add something like `datediff(second,table1.arrival_time,table2.depart_time) < X` )

table1:

```
id | eq_nb |    arival_time
-------------------------------------
1  |  25   |    05:30:15.231
-------------------------------------
2  |  50   |    06:30:15.231
-------------------------------------
3  |  7    |    07:30:15.231
-------------------------------------
1  |  25   |    08:30:15.231
-------------------------------------
5  |  27   |    09:30:15.231   
-------------------------------------
```

table2:

```
id | eq_nb |       depart_time
----------------------------------
1  |  25   |       05:31:15.231
----------------------------------
2  |  50   |       06:31:15.231
----------------------------------
3  |  7    |       07:31:15.231
----------------------------------
1  |  25   |       08:31:15.231
----------------------------------
```

desired result:

```
id | eq_nb |         arrival_time    |  depart_time
-------------------------------------------------------
1  |  25   |         05:30:15.231    |   05:31:15.231
-------------------------------------------------------
2  |  50   |         06:30:15.231    |   06:31:15.231
-------------------------------------------------------
3  |  7    |         07:30:15.231    |   07:31:15.231
-------------------------------------------------------
1  |  25   |         08:30:15.231    |   08:31:15.231
--------------------------------------------------------
5  |  27   |         09:30:15.231    |       NULL
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why do you think you will get multiple combinations with the JOIN? Have you tried it - the fact that you JOIN on the id value in each table prevents the expansion of the multiple times 25 appears.   Please show the output you get from that query

Comment: the id here is not unique, 
but you gave me an idea to generate an identifier for my tables

Comment: *"the id here is not unique"* No, but the combination of `id` and `eq_nb` appears to be. What wrong with those?

Answer (score 2):

`left join` should do what you want:

```
select *
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.eq_nb = t2.eq_nb;
```

Given your data, the `id`s are unique, so there should be no duplication.  Note:  This is equivalent to your first query; `left join` is typically easier to follow because all the rows in the first table are in the result set.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=441046c01869f32d9ae26808ca9b0f0c) is a db<>fiddle, illustrating that it works.